# sum (XXX) over (partition by yyy order by zzz) not work as expected

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery and I am going to calculate the running total of session_count within a purchaseguestid.
When the "Staty_active" is changed, the running total should be start from 0 again.
But my code didn't work as expected, as you can see, from the picture, it showing 3 after the null.

what's wrong with my code?
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSwyC.png)

```
SELECT 
  purchaseguestid,
  stay_active,
  mo,
  session_count,
  sum(session_count) over (partition by purchaseguestid, stay_active order by mo, stay_active) as RT_session_count_status,
from stay_active_status
where purchaseguestid = "00493848-e6e1-40ea-ac38-08a39e52d654"
order by purchaseguestid,mo
```

I tried to use the above code, and I expect the 3 should be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OVER (PARTION BY) clause works like a GROUP BY would work. So it groups all the combinations you entered together. The database has only two groups in your example:

- group 1: 00493848-e6e1-40ea-ac38-08a39e52d654 - true
- group 2: 00493848-e6e1-40ea-ac38-08a39e52d654 - false

With the running total mechanism it counts up your RT_session_count_status every time the session_count is != null.

As a result of this there is no reset, because there are no more seperated groups.
If you want a reset you have to define another grouping mechanism in your partition by clause.